# How Facebook and other notifications work without gmail account in sync

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

As per my knowledge as of now the only way of push notification in android is GCM, and to register a device on GCM we need a Gmail account to be synced on device so if I am developing an app using GCM for push notifications service I need to put a check of whether the Gmail account is configured and synced on device or not.

But the application like facebook, Twitter and many more never ask to add and sync a Gmail account then how they are able to use push notifications ?

Comment: Because the Gmail account is already logged in? The apps you listed also add their own account to the device.

Answer (score 0):

if you have facebook fo you once logged in yhen its send push notification,
if you wants facebook for android go to http://goo.gl/CPLFl 
there were also other paid applications for android in free.